# Master - Worker Node communication in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I have 4 `worker` nodes and 1 `master` in kubernetes cluster. I made `daemon-set` deployment from the master and it starts its pods on all the worker nodes. I have script which keeps running in background which basically monitors a `git` repository and checks if needs to be pulled. If yes, then it pulls new changes to local. Pods can only read the local files at once when it starts and then keep using those configuration. I want to somehow restart the pod on that worker so that it picks up the new changes.

Is there any way, we can notify about the new changes to the master so that master can restart the pod.? or

Master can keep track of the `git` repo and send the new changes to that worker as well as restart the pod.?

Is there any other way of achieving this functionality. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting a [CronJob](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/) on a master node and creating a persistent [volume](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/) which would be shared between the pods might help. This way all that happens on the master would be passed to the pods, and the pods would be able to read the configuration file from the volume.
You can find an [example of CronJob](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/job/automated-tasks-with-cron-jobs/) in Kubernetes documentation.

It would be better to follow the containerization philosophy to set up CI/CD tools (for example Jenkins/Bamboo/TeamCity) to automate this.  They have built-in functions that would perform the tasks you need.

Comment: Can you share any link for CI/CD tools

Comment: Here you can find the most popular [tools](https://code-maze.com/top-8-continuous-integration-tools/). From my experience, I would suggest Jenkins/GitLab, although there are many options. 
Also, some cloud providers (for example, GCP, AWS, Azure) offer easy-to-deploy images with ready-to-go CI/CD pipelines (like Jenkins).